# content editor in page Layout

Tags: web-part, page-layout

my page Layout:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>


<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">   
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server"> 
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div class="page-inner layout-02">
        <div class="oss-column oss-col-1">
                <div class="block-content" id="main-content">

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="__WebPartPageLibraryZone__"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{78D385E7-5629-4F39-8887-F5E4838FFE23}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Content</Title><FrameType>None</FrameType><Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description><IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><PartOrder>2</PartOrder><FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove><AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize><AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit><AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink /><HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall /><MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly><PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter /><ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties><ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID><ID>g_91bf0d77_993e_4782_9716_5b6b4cf5ea67</ID><ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" /><Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[]]></Content><PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" /></WebPart></WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>

                        </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

the result is i found two content editor and not one :
[image]

and the page layout in SharePointDesigner looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>


<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">   
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server"> 
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div class="page-inner layout-02">
        <div class="oss-column oss-col-1">
                <div class="block-content" id="main-content">

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="__WebPartPageLibraryZone__"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{78D385E7-5629-4F39-8887-F5E4838FFE23}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Content</Title><FrameType>None</FrameType><Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description><IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><PartOrder>2</PartOrder><FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove><AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize><AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit><AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink /><HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall /><MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly><PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter /><ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties><ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID><ID>g_91bf0d77_993e_4782_9716_5b6b4cf5ea67</ID><ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" /><Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[]]></Content><PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" /></WebPart></WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>

                        </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="__WebPartPageLibraryZone__"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{78D385E7-5629-4F39-8887-F5E4838FFE23}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Content</Title><FrameType>None</FrameType><Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description><IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><PartOrder>2</PartOrder><FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove><AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize><AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit><AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink /><HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall /><MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly><PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter /><ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties><ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID><ID>g_91bf0d77_993e_4782_9716_5b6b4cf5ea67</ID><ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" /><Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[]]></Content><PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" /></WebPart></WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

any idea , why i got this extra content editor ?

Answer (score 0):

The image above posted for **the page layout in SharePointDesigner looks like this** 
 in the question is showing two content editors on page.

Remove the the webpartzone which is outside of the PlaceholderMain ContentPlaceHolder (highlighted in red in the snapshot i have attached).
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: each time i remove this webpart (outside the asp:Content) it comeback egain ! and at the end i should not use sharepoint designer, i need to figure out a solution with VS